# Shaped windows in gtkmm

Tags: c++, cairo, gtkmm

How do I create shaped windows in Gtkmm. The shape must be defined using cairomm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairo and GTK+ are not directly relevant with shaped windows.

You need to look at GDK which is the windowing system for GTK+

Here is the respective method in vanilla (for C) GDK

http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-shape-combine-mask